# Generic method for implementing if-else statement in hardware (using gates,mux-demux,flip flops ) etc

Tags: digital-logic

I am currently working on converting a high level language into an equivalent circuit.. I am able to convert simple expressions like a+b, a.b or a combination of them using gates. But I wanted to know if there's a generic method to implement if-else statement using electronic components such as gates, mux, ff. A simple answer would be to use mux-demux. But that wouldn't solve the following problem(for example)

```
if(posedge(clock)):

q<=d
```

The construct for that would be positive edge triggered flip flop. So is there any general way to implement if-else statement?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For combinational logic, `if`/`else` is implemented as a 2:1 multiplexer. In Boolean algebra, this would be:

```
Q = (A * S) + (B * S')
```

where:

- `S` is the input fed by the `if` condition,
- `A` is the input fed by the `then` subexpression,
- `B` is the input fed by the `else` subexpression, and
- `Q` is the output of the expression.

You could theoretically generalize this to include a *single* clock edge, but it gets a lot more complex and would resemble an FPGA cell when you're done. Basically, if a clock edge were included, you could not have an `else` clause (because it is implicitly "do not change the output"), and any non-edge parts of the `if` condition would simply become the clock enable expression. Once the dust settled, you'd be left with a less-clear version of the `always_ff` statement, which you should use instead anyway.

Conditions with two or more clock edges are not synthesizable.

**EDIT:** First, I'm not sure `if(posedge(...))` is synthesizable. In general, you use the `posedge(...)` clause in the `always_ff @(...)` line and don't need the `posedge()` inside the block.

In SystemVerilog, the generic form of a 2:1 multiplexer is an `if` statement. For example:

```
always_comb begin
    if(S)
        Q = A;
    else
        Q = B;
end
```

If there's a clock edge, though, you need to use a flip-flop:

```
always_ff @(posedge CLK) begin
    if(CLK_ENA)
        Q <= D;
end
```

Adding an asynchronous reset looks like this:

```
always_ff @(posedge RESET, posedge CLK) begin
    if(RESET)
        Q <= '0;
    else if(CLK_ENA)
        Q <= D;
end
```

In this case, RESET is active-high.  Note that you only need to say RESET is edge sensitive in the `@()` part. In the rest of the block, RESET will have the level *after* the edge. Also note that the edge-sensitivities are a list; you can't say "and". (In original Verilog, you separated edge sensitivities with "or", misleading people into thinking "and" could work as well.)

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your reply!...however when I am generalizing what do I use as S ? ( i have a posedge(clk)...i.e an attribute of a signal and not a signal itself)....also could you kindly explain what do u meant by "any non edge part of if condition become clock enable expression"...thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "^ ........"?

Comment: I realized I hadn't tagged you in my reply to your comment...so I wrote another comment to direct you to the first one!...hence the ^ ....  i used the remaining dots since a comment has to be longer than 15 characters :D ...anyway could you please solve my query ?

Comment: An answerer gets notified of *all* comments to their answer, so I didn't miss you. You only need to use the tag if you were replying to a commenter. As to your queries, first, see the combinational example for where S is. Since you have an edge in your condition, you can't use combinational logic, and must use a flip-flop instead. As to your second query, see the flip flop example above. It could be thought of as `if(CLK_ENA & posedge(CLK))`; note that part of that condition is `posedge()` and part is not.

Comment: thanks for the reply!..but how would you in general synthesize a code with more than one element in the sensitivity?..i mean having one element in the sensitivity list I can feed it to the clock..but what about two elements there?..I believe "reset idea" wont always work..and what if it is more than 2?   Thanks!!

Comment: The `posedge RESET` sensitivity *only* works if there is an asynchronous reset on your flip-flop; otherwise, it becomes unsynthesizable. Flip-flops with two or more clocks don't exist in production, so having two or more clocks in the sensitivity list will not synthesize.  It can be simulated, just not synthesized.  (There's a lot of legal Verilog and VHDL that can't be synthesized; these languages are primarily simulation languages and only tangentially synthesis languages.) If you think you need multiple sensitivities, you need to refactor your design.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a simple combination of an AND and XOR?  AND has logic being tested and second is tied to high.  XOR has logic being tested and second is tied high.

### AND (IF)

0  (1) = 0

1  (1) = 1

### XOR (ELSE)

0  (1) = 1

1  (1) = 0

Comment: Strictly speaking, since else is a catch-all, wouldn't `nand` be more appropriate than `xor`?